# Use jquery Input value window prompt in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is have a window prompt / alert box pop up with a text input. I want the value of the text in my jQuery code to be used in place of the word YOU in the a tag in my html document.

jQuery code I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var userName = window.prompt("Please Enter Your Name", "Text");
});
```

My html

```
<body>
  <center><h1 class="Logo">Welcome to<br>an epic story adventure<br>starring <a>YOU!</a></h1></center>
  <p></p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/name.js"></script>
</body>
```

so basically, I wanna replace `YOU!` with the input value of the window prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd just need to add this line after the userName JavaScript line you have:

```
$('h1.Logo a').text(userName);
```

On a side note, don't use the `<center>` element; it's not valid anymore. Use CSS instead. Also, a `<span>` might be more appropriate than an `<a>` tag in your example.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I've been sitting here for the past couple hours searching youtube tutorials and google!